# How to install older CURL on Linux(I have older PHP version)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl

I need to add curl to my PHP, I read multiple articles which recommended just `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

But when I try it I get error as below

Error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> dropbox : Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be
>   installed
>
> php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.45-1~dotdeb+6.1) but
>   5.4.31-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed

So I go a bit deeper and try to install it manualy, so I basicly download curl from curl website with: `wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.36.0.tar.gz`
and then just unpack it and just `./configure` and `sudo make` and after that `sudo make install`

Dispite the fact i didnt get any error It also didnt help.

From error I see that I have older version of my PHP than one in repository but I really have no clue what I can do now.

Is here anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with that version of PHP, you can build the cURL extension yourself and then activate it with PHP.  Normally, cURL is compiled into the PHP binary but you can also run it as a dynamic extension.

When you downloaded, compiled, and installed cURL, this installed the curl program and libraries but has nothing to do with PHP.

You can follow these steps to build a cURL PHP extension for your system:

- Go to http://php.net/releases and download the source code for the version of PHP you are currently running
- Extract to a temporary location
- From the command line, `cd` to php-5.x.x/ext/curl
- Run the following commands:
- `phpize`
- `./configure --with-curl=/usr/local` (/usr/local should be correct, but you can try leaving it blank, or specify the `--prefix` you used when you installed cURL.
- `make && make install`

After `make install` runs, it should say something like:

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php5/20121212/
```

This is where it will place `curl.so`

Now, edit your `php.ini` file that PHP uses and add:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Restart your webserver &/or PHP, check that cURL is loaded.

Note: If you don't have the `phpize` (it should have come with PHP) you might need to just build PHP to a temporary location and copy `phpize` to `/usr/bin` so you have it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your PHP version and then install curl.

Do `apt-get update` to get the latest definitions, then `apt-get upgrade` to upgrade all packages, then `apt-get install php5-curl`.

Comment: and if this doesn't help try to do `apt-get -f install`

Comment: is it safe to do something like this on server where real website is running?

Comment: No.  Do it in your test or staging environment first.